# Lodash: how simplify

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to simplify next code:

```
rules = rules.map(x => Object.assign(x, x.ruleOption.options))
rules.forEach(x => delete x.ruleOption)
rules = _.keyBy(rules, 'code')
```

I start active use the Lodash, and try to understand right using-way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with the [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get `ruleOption`, and create a new object with `ruleOption`. You can then use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to combine `ruleOptions.options` with the rest of the object:

```js
const rules = [{ code: 'x', ruleOption: { options: { type: 'a' }}}, { code: 'y', ruleOption: { options: { type: 'b' }}}];

const newRules = _.keyBy(
  rules.map(({ ruleOption, ...obj }) => ({ ...obj, ...ruleOption.options })),
  'code'
)

console.log(newRules)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```